# Graphing Software - a faq?

Tags: discussion, images

I noticed another in the line of graphing-software questions. This means we now have [Draw customized (calculus) graphs like these?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32512/draw-customized-calculus-graphs-like-these), [What is a good graphing software?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26903/what-is-a-good-graphing-software), [Software for plotting a graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55570/software-for-plotting-a-graph), [A good, free, graphics package for mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5837/a-good-free-graphics-package-for-mathematics), [Educational Math Software](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870/educational-math-software).

There are also a few (redundant, I think) questions on graph theory style graphing software, but those don't concern me as much. I don't know much about how the faq questions (like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq), as opposed to the site faq) come to exist, but perhaps this should be one too?

What is the policy on faq questions, and is there any reason not to condense the questions above into a single, super-graphing question?

Comment: In regards to the (faq)-tagged questions: see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions

Comment: Might be another [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13841/online-tool-for-making-graphs-vertices-and-edges/13843#13843).